# Two-view triangulation drifting for points from same pose

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, pose-estimation

I am encountering a strange issue with the triangulation function of openCV. For my two-view pose estimation tests, I was doing this:

Case 1: A single camera taking pictures of a scene from two views, then computing the essential matrix and triangulating the scene: which worked reasonably well.

Case 2: I am trying to do this with two cameras (both calibrated), but triangulation is failing. For image pairs from the same poses, the triangulated points should be more or less the same (and indeed they were in case 1), but now, they are drifting.

Example:

```
t1 = [0.9950924870426178, 0.0518147862900856, -0.08429810290303305] (cam 2 at 0, 0, 0)
Homogenized feature match: (-0.1558, -0.1504, 1); (-0.0574, -0.1619, 1);
Triangulated point: [-4.8177, -4.6760, 30.92588]

t2 = [0.9962326376676536, 0.05676863562110455, -0.08508433760191333] (approx. the same as before)
Homogenized feature match: (-0.1557, -0.1504, 1); (-0.0574, -0.1619, 1); (approx. the same)
Triangulated point: [-2.3599, -2.3053, 15.1603]
```

What am I doing wrong here?  For the next set of points, triangulatePoints comes up with another weird estimate.

Comment: did you correct lens distortion of both cameras?

Comment: Yes. I used cv::undistort()